# Mockito mocking a method calls the actual method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock method `createInstanceB()` using `Mockito.when()` as well as `doReturn()`. This always calls real method.

For example:

```
Class A {
  public B createInstanceB(any, any) {
    B b = new B();
    b.api();
  }
}
```

I am using the code below

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

    Class ATest {
      A a;
      B b;

      @Before
      Public void setup{
        a = A.getInstance();
        b = mock(B.class);
      }
  
      @Test
      public void testCreateInstanceB(){
        Mockito.when(a.createInstanceB(any(),any()).thenReturn(b);
        ...
      }
    }
```

I tried `doReturn(mock)` as well.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. We can't tell why your code is wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: Updated - JB Nizet

Comment: The code you posted is not valid Java code. And as the response you got correctly says: you're trying to mock methods of an object that is not a mock. That can't work.

Comment: And in that sense, the real answer is that you should read a good tutorial. It is not efficient to learn by trial and error in this case.

Answer (score 18):

As StvnBrkdll recommended, use a Spy if you're needing to use an actual instance. But that can still call the real method sometimes if using Mockito.when() as you are in your example. As an alternative, look at Mockito.doReturn(). For example using your code: `Mockito.doReturn(b).when(a).createInstanceB(any(),any());` This will now only return `b` and never call the actual method of `createInstanceB`.

Btw, [their docs](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy) have a section about this. See the part under "**Important gotcha on spying real objects!**"

Answer (score 6):

The problem with the code is that it is calling `Mockito.when()` on an actual instance of `A`, not a mock. `Mockito.when()` only works with mock objects, not the real thing.

If you need to have methods "mocked" (stubbed) on "real" objects, consider using `Mockito.spy()`. For more information on using "spies", [see this post](http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy).

Something like this will be close to what you want:

```
Class ATest{
A a ;
A aSpy;
B b;

@Before
Public void setup{
  a = A.getInstance();
  aSpy = Mockito.spy(a);
  b = mock(B.class);
}

@Test
public void testCreateInstanceB(){
 Mockito.when(aSpy.createInstanceB(any(),any()).thenReturn(b);
 ...
}
```

You will need to use `aSpy`, not `a` in your test code.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem. Both of these methods `thenReturn()` and `doReturn()` seem to do the same in my case: that is they are calling the actual method. Using `stub` worked for me:

```
PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(A.class, "createInstance", argtypes)).toReturn(b);
```

Make sure you mock the constructor of `A` as well as using `PowerMockito.whenNew()` if you create a new object and add `A.class` to `@PrepareForTest`.

Answer (score 1):

As per [@StvnBrkdll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45120656/6654475), in my case the problem was that I was using the `@Autowired` annotation instead of `@MockBean` for the method I was trying to mock, and that was causing the real implementation to be called.